# Socket.io Disconnect Ping timeout error

Tags: node.js, sockets, unity-game-engine, socket.io

we used client side unity 3D and server side node.js

Hear set ping time interval in node js for socket connection .

`io = module.exports = require('socket.io').listen(secureServer,{pingTimeout: 7000, pingInterval: 10000});
io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling","websocket","polling", "htmlfile"]);`

When disconnect socket server get error ping timeout but client (Unity 3D) not get any disconnect error.

how can i solve this issue from server side?

Answer (score -1):

`pingInterval: 10000` means : every 10000 mili secs , send packet (ping) to client for check connection , and client send to server packet (pong).
`pingTimeout: 7000` means : when send packet (ping) to client , if client have pong in 7000 mili secs , connection is ok , else connection is ended.

Now you must be set `pingInterval` and `pingTimeout` in unity code for check connection.